# How can I fit a Scala Array in a Spark DataFrame column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

My problem is that I'm working with a DataFrame and I want to:

1) Get one column with `val column = dataframe.select("columnName").collect()` or similar

2) Perform some operations on this array. This part is not clear yet, but will result in a change on some of the elements of the array

3) Overwrite the column of the DataFrame with the results from 2)

Which would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Think you need an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should either

- collect the column together with an unique id such that you can join it back to your dataframe (you can convert your transformed array back to a dataframe using `array.toDF`). However this option does not scale as you need to collect to the driver process
- apply an UDF if your logic is applicable on a per-row basis

Comment: I don´t think the first option is good for me if it doesn't scale well. I suppose I can an udf then. This would imply creating a function with the logic of the changes that I want to perform on the column and apply it with `withColumn`, is that correct?